# Why apt-cache policy shows wrong version for deb on mirror

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, wine, apt

If I run `apt-cache policy wine`, I would see the version of packet as follows

```
wine:
  Installed: 1.6.2-20
  Candidate: 1.6.2-20
  Version table:
     1.8.6-5 0
       650 http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.6.2-20 0
       700 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

But I can't install it with `apt-get install wine=1.8.6-5`. Apt fails with following:

```
Err http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ testing/main wine all 1.8.6-5
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Err http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ testing/main wine64 amd64 1.8.6-5
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Err http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ testing/main libwine amd64 1.8.6-5
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
Err http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/ testing/main fonts-wine all 1.8.6-5
  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/pool/main/w/wine/wine_1.8.6-5_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/pool/main/w/wine/wine64_1.8.6-5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/pool/main/w/wine/libwine_1.8.6-5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/pool/main/w/wine/fonts-wine_1.8.6-5_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 213.180.204.183 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

As I recognized, there is no such version in the mirror. There is another one, different from one I've tried.

[image: Mirror]

So why such a situation occured and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like its name says, `apt-cache` will show you information from the *local cache* of package data. That is, it *thinks* that the mirror still has version 1.8.6-5 because you haven't updated that cache in a long time.

If you're getting 404 errors during package downloads, you need to `apt-get update` to refresh this cache, and it's also a sign that it may be time to upgrade all packages as well.

Comment: Yep, it was `apt-get update`, simply